# Silverstripe only framework, use only framework part without base CMS

Tags: php, silverstripe

Silverstripe has an awesome framework has anybody found any tutorials or examples how to take the framework and make own admin or CMS of your own?

Comment: has it image manipulation functions like SS?

Comment: There are all sorts of PHP libraries you can use for image manipulation. The most popular one I've seen used with Laravel is https://github.com/Intervention/image.

Answer (score 4):

Just don't install the CMS. Setup your routes (`routes.yml`), controllers (`RootURLController` and others) and templates (`RootURLController.ss` etc...), and you're done. The Framework actually comes with the admin side, which you can use for Member/Security management, and `ModelAdmin`!

- http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/controllers/routing/
- http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/controllers/introduction/
- http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/templates/rendering_templates/
- http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/modeladmin/

Comment: Thaks you for information

Answer (score 0):

It's not that different. Just remove the cms folder and do your things with the controller.

http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/controllers/introduction/

Comment: Thaks you for information